# init process' nice level

Tags: debian, init, nice

The `init` process on a Debian server (VPS) I've inherited has its `nice` value set to `+10`.

There's nothing particularly obscure installed on the system. It has a LAMP stack and does a lot of IO and will need upgrading soon.

My suspicion is that a previous admin set it (either by accident or not), so would like to know if setting a `nice` value for `init` has any real benefit/purpose. I'm aware init is special, and I've never observed an init process using CPU or MEM, so it seems strange to set its `nice` value.

Answer (score 0):

Since every process inherits its parent's nice value, and all of them are below init, my guess is it was set that value to prevent any other future process on the system to have a higher value than it.